# Recovering a continuous function from a discrete one.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, dirac-delta

Consider a well-behaved function $f(x)$ defined on $x\geq0$, and construct a discretized version of it using the Dirac-delta function:

$$
f_{\Delta_x}(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n\Delta_x)\delta(x - n\Delta_x).
$$

If we let $\Delta_x \to 0$ in the above, do we recover $f(x)$?

The following notation might be sloppy, but what I mean is:

$$
\lim_{\Delta_x \to 0} f_{\Delta_x}(x)=f(x) \quad ?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Convergence
$
\lim_{\Delta_x \to 0} f_{\Delta_x}=f
$
is true in the sense of distributions.
I would say (vaguely) that you can only recover $f$ as some kind of a weak limit of $f_{\Delta_x}$, not a strong one.

Without trying to make a statement with optimal assumptions, the following holds:
if $f$ is continuous, then for any continuous, compactly supported $\phi:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ you have
$$
\lim_{\Delta_x \to 0}
\langle f_{\Delta_x},\phi\rangle
=
\langle f,\phi\rangle.
$$
Here, formally at least, $\langle f,\phi\rangle=\int_0^\infty f(x)\phi(x)dx$.